# Наложение полупрозрачного градиента на всю страницу

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема:

Требовалось наложить эффект scanline на всю html страницу.
Пытался использовать `html:before`, оно работает, но не работает наведение на другие элементы, так как `html:before` перекрывает страницу.

Возможно ли сделать это без перехода на js, так как используются сложные css стили?

Upd:
https://jsfiddle.net/yvq528fy/

Comment: добавьте **pointer-events:none** для **html:after**

Comment: если конечно устраивает, что поддержка: ie11+

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, чтобы была ясна проблема.

Comment: Есть у меня идея, но зависит от того на сколько сложен этот ваш "сканлайн". Так что да, нужен хотя бы макет.

Comment: @Cheg да, это решение, но хотелось бы подобие решения для хотя бы ie10+

Comment: @MedvedevDev linear-gradient

Comment: @Zekfad, чем градиент отличается от картинки в ::before?

Comment: @MedvedevDev Ничем, просто уточнил. Вы ведь спрашивали.

Comment: @MedvedevDev прикрепил кусок кода.

Comment: хм, в общем могу накидать вариант, но без js не получится, так как неизвестно сколько таких линий должно быть.

Comment: @MedvedevDev если js не затронет сторонние библиотеки, такие как jquery то вполне хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html::before {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: увы, нет объяснений.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, какие объяснения предлагаешь добавить?

Comment: например, в двух словах описать, **почему** у автора вопроса «не работает», и **что** именно вы предлагаете для того, чтобы «заработало». (не могу дать более конкретный совет ввиду слабого знакомства с веб-дизайном).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, предлагаю добавить свойство `pointer-events`, со значением, которое задаёт "прозрачность" для мыши - т. е. пользователь элемент видит, но все перемещения мыши и клики достаются элементам, находящимся под ним. Собственно ровно то, что решает описанную в вопросе проблему.

Comment: вот! что-то типа этого и хотелось бы видеть в тексте ответа. «просто кусок кода», всё-таки, лучше оставить для комментариев. а в ответе хорошо бы приводить объяснение/обоснование. ну, чтобы предлагаемую идею понял не только гуру в данной предметной области, но и какой-нибудь начинающий, например.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, но ведь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: ну, если объяснение/обоснование сопровождается ещё и ссылкой на конкретный пункт в документации, то это вообще отлично!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько это все ужасно, но почему бы и нет? xDD

```js
$(() => {
  const $window = $(window),
    $scanline = $('.scanline'),
    distance = 2;
    
  scanlineCreate();
  $window.on('resize', scanlineCreate);
  
  function scanlineCreate() {
    const windowHeight = $window.height();
    
    $scanline.remove('.scanline_item');

    for(let i = 0; i < windowHeight / (distance + 1); i++) {
      $scanline.append($('<div>', {
        class: 'scanline_item',
        style: `box-shadow: 0 ${(distance + 1) * i}px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)`
      }));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.scanline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.scanline_item {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
}

.link {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: pink
}

.link:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="link">Йа ссылко</a></p>
<div class="scanline"></div>
<p><a href="#" class="link">Йа ссылко тож</a></p>
```

Comment: Как вариант не плох, но только вот при скроллинге это выглядит очень жестоко. xD.

Comment: @Zekfad, ну, можно и без позишен фиксед, переписать?)

Comment: @Zekfad, хм, поскроллил, вроде норм, что не так со скроллом?)

Comment: рябит в прямом смысле.

Comment: @Zekfad, увеличьте дистанцию между полосами (если по задумке это разрешено) - увеличьте значение `distance`

Comment: Это именно ~~баг~~ фича слабых ПК.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter:blur(10px);
//css размытие
```